# Use bash alias name in a function that was called using that alias

Tags: bash, function, alias

I'm playing a [game in a terminal](http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/). It uses ssh connection and have a different pair of user and password for each level.

I use my bash aliases to store those pairs, i.e. I have an alias for each level where I call a bash function with 2 parameters: password and number of level.

```
function log.as.bandit() {
    sshpass -p $1 ssh bandit$2@bandit.labs.overthewire.org
}
alias bandit14="log.as.bandit secretPass 14"
alias bandit15="log.as.bandit differentSecretPass 15"
```

It would be even easier for me if I could pass as a parameter only password and take the username from an alias that I used.

**Question:**
Is that possible to use alias name in a function that has been called by that alias?

In the example:

```
function log.as.bandit() {
    sshpass -p $1 ssh $HERE_I_DEREFERENCE_THE_ALIAS_NAME@bandit.labs.overthewire.org
}
alias bandit14="log.as.bandit secretPass"
alias bandit15="log.as.bandit differentSecretPass"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know: no, you can't do that with aliases.

But what you can do is:

```
function log.as.bandit() {
    sshpass -p "$1" ssh "${FUNCNAME[1]}"@bandit.labs.overthewire.org
}
bandit14() { log.as.bandit secretPass; }
bandit15() { log.as.bandit differentSecretPass; }
```

i.e. use functions instead of aliases.

`FUNCNAME` is an array containing the names of the currently executing functions. `${FUNCNAME[0]}` is the name of the current function itself (`log.as.bandit`); `${FUNCNAME[1]}` is the name of the calling function (`bandit14` or `bandit15`).

Comment: I forgot to write that I was thinking of a similar way as with `const char* argv[]` in C. This works and it is new piece of knowledge for me- thanks